# Google Maps Flutter - How to apply styles to info window?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps

I have a Google Map applied with flutter_maps, some markers and a info window to each marker.

- App: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gy2D.png
- Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nICi1.png

I'm able to put some HTML into it, but for some reason `class` and `style` does not appear in chrome dev tools

- App: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ed3eY.png
- Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/buSrx.png

So, how can I apply styles to the info window? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please avoid posting image of your code and read [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve the chances of getting an answer.